# custom shape with canvas or etc in jetpack compose

Tags: java, android, kotlin

hi how can i create a shape like this in jetpack compose

[image]

and How can you shade it?(need to give it shadow )

I try to use 2 ovals in top and front of an box and push them
but its not a good way

it takes a lot of time
thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it is with custom polygons [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/shapes#custom-polygons). The implementation is a bit lengthy, you might want to alter `vertices` and `rounding` values to customize the shape. Shadow is added with `shadowElevation` parameter of `graphicsLayer` modifier.

[image]

Add dependency to your `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation("androidx.graphics:graphics-shapes:1.0.0-alpha05")
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomShape() {
    val clipShape = remember {
        RoundedPolygonShape(polygon)
    }
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width = 200.dp, height = 100.dp)
            .graphicsLayer {
                shadowElevation = 6.dp.toPx()
                shape = clipShape
                clip = true
            },
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text("Content")
        }
    }
}

private fun createPolygon(): RoundedPolygon {
    val vertices = {
        val cornerX = 1f
        val cornerY = 0.90f
        val topBotX = 0f
        val topBotY = 1f
        floatArrayOf(
            // top left
            -cornerX,
            -cornerY,
            // top
            topBotX,
            -topBotY,
            // top right
            cornerX,
            -cornerY,
            // bottom right
            cornerX,
            cornerY,
            // bottom
            topBotX,
            topBotY,
            // bottom left
            -cornerX,
            cornerY,
        )
    }
    val rounding = {
        val roundingCorner = 0.1f
        val roundingTopBot = 5f
        listOf(
            CornerRounding(roundingCorner),
            CornerRounding(roundingTopBot),
            CornerRounding(roundingCorner),
            CornerRounding(roundingCorner),
            CornerRounding(roundingTopBot),
            CornerRounding(roundingCorner),
        )
    }
    return RoundedPolygon(vertices = vertices(), perVertexRounding = rounding())
}

private val polygon = createPolygon()

class RoundedPolygonShape(
    private val polygon: RoundedPolygon
) : Shape {
    private val matrix = Matrix()
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val path = polygon.cubics.toPath()
        matrix.scale(size.width / 2f, size.height / 2f)
        matrix.translate(1f, 1f)
        path.transform(matrix)
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}

private fun List<Cubic>.toPath(path: Path = Path(), scale: Float = 1f): Path {
    path.rewind()
    firstOrNull()?.let { first ->
        path.moveTo(first.anchor0X * scale, first.anchor0Y * scale)
    }
    for (bezier in this) {
        path.cubicTo(
            bezier.control0X * scale, bezier.control0Y * scale,
            bezier.control1X * scale, bezier.control1Y * scale,
            bezier.anchor1X * scale, bezier.anchor1Y * scale
        )
    }
    path.close()
    return path
}
```